# Prevent button from closing dropdown menu - Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I hope you will help a complete newbie on caught on deep water =)

I would like this dropdown form to stay open when clicking the button 'Hent', (This should make their  of documents appear below the button, which they do, the client just has to reopen the dropdown, which is poor and annoying usability)  unfortunately I am really new to javascript, which seems to be the way to fix this and I cannot get the 'stop propagation' soutions to work. `$(document).on('click', 'someyourContainer .dropdown-menu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`
I believe it might be because, they are targeting the entire dropdown and not the button action.

To make things even better, the `id onclick="do_search()` is Ajax, which I know even less about - so Ill add the code, in case the solution can be found here.

Fiddle of the nav: https://jsfiddle.net/NUJ88/kgnw6dpq/14/

and Jquery/ajax code:

```
function do_search () {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: window.location.protocol + "#",
    data: { 
      "tagid": jQuery("#tagbox").val(), 
      "lang": jQuery("#langbox").val()
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery("#results").html(data);
    }
  });
};
    
function key_pressed(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    do_search();
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: your fiddle is not functional.

Comment: Strange - it works perfectly when Im logged in, but I do se that it doesnt when I log out.